# Can't insert in pivot table for the "belongsToMany" relationship

Tags: php, laravel

**I have** models `Roles` and `Permissions` linked with `belongsToMany` relationship:

```
class Role extends Model
{
    ...

    public function permissions()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Permission', 'role_permissions');
    }

    ...
}


class Permission extends Model
{
    ...

    public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Role', 'role_permissions');
    }

    ...
}
```

From the DB perspective, I have tables: `roles`, `permissions` and pivot table: `role_permissions` (with columns `role_id`, `permission_id`).

**I'm trying** to save role with its permissions:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    ...

    $role = Role::create([
        'slug' => $request->slug,
        'display_name' => $request->display_name,
        'parent_id' => $request->parent_id,
        ...
    ]);

    $role->permissions()->attach($request->permissions);

    ...
}
```

as we can see in the official [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships).

**I'm getting** an error:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect integer value: '[6,1]' for column 'permission_id' at row 1 (SQL: insert into `role_permissions` (`permission_id`, `role_id`) values ([6,1], 7))

It's trying to save the relationships array in one field. Tried with the `sync(..)` method; result is the same.

Shouldn't it be handled by Laravel? What am I missing here?

Laravel version is the latest [8.x]. Thanks.

Comment: Iterate `$request->permissions` and attach every value instead.

Comment: @FelippeDuarte thanks for the comment. It's how it supposed to work or a workaround? Can't see such solution in the documentation.

Comment: I can't remember if there is a way to pass multiple at once, but the docs doesn't says different from that.

Comment: @FelippeDuarte thanks again for the comment, `$user->roles()->attach([
    1 => ['expires' => $expires],
    2 => ['expires' => $expires],
]);` - from documentation. Am I missing something?

Comment: `$request->permissions` is an array? Maybe you need to force as array before pass to function like `$role->permissions()->attach((array)$request->permissions);`

Comment: `dd($request->permissions)` to see what is the value. It must be an array of ids to be attached

Comment: @FelippeDuarte actually I needed to `json_decode` the `$request->permissions`. Everything is correct. Thanks for your time and support.